# unable to set property in an object using defineProperty method

Tags: javascript

I have defined an object and defining a property using javascript's defineProperty method.

```
var obj ={};
Object.defineProperty(obj,'b',{get:function(){
return 5},
set:function(value){
this.b = value}
});
```

but when i am setting the value of b using below statement

```
obj.b = 25
```

it giving me

**RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

How can i set the value of b?

Comment: remove `this` from `b`. set it as `b=value` in set method, let me know if works.

Comment: which is your browser? is it compatible with defineProperty?

Comment: i am not doing this on browser. i am using node's repl. @RicardoPontual

Comment: @DeendayalGarg by using this i am unable to change the value as my get function always return me 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using setter in infinite recursive loop, code inside setter is using it again:

```
this.b = value; //this use setter of b again
```

change it to any different variable name like:

```
this.bVal=value;
```

All code:

```js
//example object
obj={};

Object.defineProperty(obj,'b',{
get:function(){
  return this.bVal;
},
set:function(value){
  this.bVal=value;
}
});

obj.b="Test text value of property b";
console.log(obj.b);
```

Why previous code was infinite loop? Take a look:

```
obj.b=12; //this code run set function
```

Inside `set` function was:

```
this.b=value; //this code also runs set function because this===obj
```

So `set` function is called again and again and never stops.

Comment: i just not get it . how setter is in infinite loop??

Comment: @AtulAgrawal I add some more information, check if it is clear now.

Comment: @AtulAgrawal great!